# How to save data from webpage in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, url

I want to simply save the data(html code) of the webpage in MATLAB using url. Like

```
url='http://192.168.4.1';
str=somefunction(URL);
disp(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
% Example url
urldef='http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/Jon/R_SC/Module3/ExampleData3.txt';
[str status]=urlread(urldef);
disp(str);
```

For more info, please read the [urlread docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/urlread.html).

Comment: It's working fine with the websites on internet like http://wipp.in but It's not working when I try to use the URL to the webserver created using Wi-Fi module(interfaced with arduino UNO) sending this data `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>Start</p></body></html>`.

Comment: Does it raise any errors? Also this does not change the fact that to read urls you should use *urlread*. I have just tried to read from shortened urls (wipp.in/TbugOq9) and a local website I am developing (0.0.0.0:5000) and I could retrieve the data without any problems. You might want to check if the UNO Wifi module is really working. It looks like a connectivity issue, not how you read the data from Matlab